# How to implement an async wcf client for a synchronous service

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

Is there a way to create an async client for a synchronous WCF service without adding a service reference?  This is for a .NET 4 client.

Answer (score 3):

A service reference in Visual Studio is nothing else than a code generator that creates a proxy class with corresponding data elements necessary to call your web service. Of course you can hand build a proxy if you really want to go over tedious and boring work.

Maybe start by decompiling System.ServiceModel.ClientBase using .net reflector?

Do some research on ChannelFactory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channelfactory.aspx

Even when implementing my own client by wrapping a ChannelFactory, I am still using the Add Service reference in another project to create the class definitions and move them into the real project. That's a good compromise.

Here's a simple async service interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "IService")]
public interface IServiceAsync
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginGetStuff(string someData, AsyncCallback callback, object state);

    IEnumerable<Stuff> EndGetStuff(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

The .NET contract might look like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Stuff> GetStuff(string someData);
}
```

Then in code, assuming you use HTTP, No security and binary message encoding, something like this (Sorry I haven't compiled any of this, just typed it using some of the code I have written for projects):

```
//Create a binding for the proxy to use
HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransportBindingElement;

httpTransportBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
absoluteServiceUri = new Uri(absoluteServiceUri.OriginalString + BinaryEndpointUri, UriKind.Absolute);
}

//Create the message encoding binding element - we'll specify binary encoding
var binaryMessageEncoding = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();

//Add the binding elements into a Custom Binding            
var customBinding = new CustomBinding(binaryMessageEncoding, httpTransportBindingElement);

// Set send timeout
customBinding.SendTimeout = this.SendTimeout;   

var factory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceAsync>(customBinding, new EndpointAddress(absoluteServiceUri, new AddressHeader[0]));

var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
channel.BeginGetStuff(Bla, results => { // Do something }, null);
```